# pgfplots: Interaction of "fill between" with scope and foreach loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, foreach, fillbetween, scoping

I intend to create several plots in different places, each with `fill between` areas, using the `foreach` loop. While all other plot lines do appear as expected for every iteration of the loop, the areas are not filled.

Something similar happens when placing an axis with `fill between` inside a scope. Check out this MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[at={(0cm,2cm)},
        axis x line=none, axis y line=none,
        width=5cm, height=2cm, clip=false, anchor=origin,
        xmin=0, xmax=1, ymin=-1, ymax=1,
        trig format plots=rad ]
    \addplot[blue, samples=21, domain=0:1, name path=sin1] plot {sin(pi*x)};
    \addplot[blue, samples=21, domain=0:1, name path=sin2] plot {-sin(pi*x)};
    \addplot[blue!10] fill between [of=sin1 and sin2];
    \end{axis}

\begin{scope}
    \begin{axis}[at={(0cm,1cm)},
        axis x line=none, axis y line=none,
        width=5cm, height=2cm, clip=false, anchor=origin,
        xmin=0, xmax=1, ymin=-1, ymax=1,
        trig format plots=rad ]
    \addplot[blue, samples=21, domain=0:1, name path=sin3] plot {sin(pi*x)};
    \addplot[blue, samples=21, domain=0:1, name path=sin4] plot {-sin(pi*x)};
    \addplot[blue!10] fill between [of=sin3 and sin4];
    \end{axis}
\end{scope}

\foreach \j in {1} {
    \begin{axis}[at={(0cm,0cm)},
        axis x line=none, axis y line=none,
        width=5cm, height=2cm, clip=false, anchor=origin,
        xmin=0, xmax=1, ymin=-1, ymax=1,
        trig format plots=rad ]
    \addplot[blue, samples=21, domain=0:1, name path=sin5] plot {sin(\j*pi*x)};
    \addplot[blue, samples=21, domain=0:1, name path=sin6] plot {-sin(\j*pi*x)};
    \addplot[blue!10] fill between [of=sin5 and sin6];
    \end{axis}
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When the first axis is **not** commented out, all areas are being filled as expected. However, when the whole first axis **is** commented out, the two area in the other two axes are not being filled.

Does someone know why this happens, and/or how to get the bottom two axis environments working correctly without the first?

Comment: If you remove the `\foreach` block, the `scope` block works just fine. The culprit is really just the `\foreach` part of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place the `\foreach` loop inside the `axis` environment and use `fill between` only after the loop.

If you need to enclose the whole `axis` in the loop, you can try using `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped` or `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach`. I am unable to explain, however, why these macros work in this case and `\foreach` does not.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[at={(0cm,0cm)},
    axis x line=none, axis y line=none,
    width=5cm, height=2cm, clip=false, anchor=origin,
    xmin=0, xmax=1, ymin=-1, ymax=1,
    trig format plots=rad ]
\foreach \j in {1} {
    \addplot[blue, samples=21, domain=0:1, name path=sin5] plot {sin(\j*pi*x)};
    \addplot[blue, samples=21, domain=0:1, name path=sin6] plot {-sin(\j*pi*x)};
}
\addplot[blue!10] fill between [of=sin5 and sin6];
\end{axis}

\pgfplotsforeachungrouped \j in {1} {
    \begin{axis}[at={(0cm,1cm)},
        axis x line=none, axis y line=none,
        width=5cm, height=2cm, clip=false, anchor=origin,
        xmin=0, xmax=1, ymin=-1, ymax=1,
        trig format plots=rad ]
    \addplot[blue, samples=21, domain=0:1, name path=sin5] plot {sin(\j*pi*x)};
    \addplot[blue, samples=21, domain=0:1, name path=sin6] plot {-sin(\j*pi*x)};
    \addplot[blue!10] fill between [of=sin5 and sin6];
    \end{axis}
}

\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1}{
    \begin{axis}[at={(0cm,2cm)},
        axis x line=none, axis y line=none,
        width=5cm, height=2cm, clip=false, anchor=origin,
        xmin=0, xmax=1, ymin=-1, ymax=1,
        trig format plots=rad ]
    \addplot[blue, samples=21, domain=0:1, name path=sin5] plot {sin(#1*pi*x)};
    \addplot[blue, samples=21, domain=0:1, name path=sin6] plot {-sin(#1*pi*x)};
    \addplot[blue!10] fill between [of=sin5 and sin6];
    \end{axis}
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the very quick reply! I apologize for not expressing myself clearly enough. My goal is to have several axes in different places (shifted along y, say) with fill between plots each. I don't think I can achieve this with a foreach loop inside the axis environment. :-(

Comment: @FlorianL I see, but you could perhaps with `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped` or `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` which I proposed as alternatives.

Comment: Oh, yes, that actually does exactly what I want. Sorry, I didn't realize this before. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @FlorianL I am actually not quite sure why the `\foreach` does not work in this case. I think it is because it first collects the path information and only later prints it. Maybe this conflicts in some way with the `fill between` mechanism. Probably someone with more expertise in this field is able to answer the "why" part of your question.